# Asking for user input to create two arrays

Tags: arrays, for-loop, user-input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ch7AssignArrays1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] population = new int[5];// array to store populations for counties
        String[] county = new String[5]; //array to store county names

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //ask user for county name and store in array
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of a county: ");
        county[0] = input.toString();
        //ask user for population of county entered above, store in array
        System.out.println("Enter the population of the county: " + input.nextLine());
        population[0] = input.nextInt();


        for(int index = 1; index < county.length && index < population.length; index++){
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of a county: ");
            county[index] = input.toString();
            //ask user for population of county entered above, store in array
            System.out.println("Enter the population of the county: ");
            System.out.println(input.hasNext());
            population[index] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for(int index = 0; index < county.length && index < population.length;index++){
        System.out.println(county[index] + "\t" + population[index]);
        }
    }

}
```

I have written this code and am having an issue when the program reaches the for loop. I want to be able to ask for a user input, store into one array(county), then ask again for input and store into the other array(population), then print both arrays at the end. This works fine with the input.nextLine outside of the for loop, each question is asked then stored. But when in the loop, both questions are asked at once and input is only taken for the second array (population). The solution that I found for outside the for loop does not work inside the loop. What can I put in the for loop that would fix this?

Answer (score 1):

My issue was my code line  county[0] = input.toString(); should be .next() to solve the multiple user inputs issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mallory L, this is a good question.

It'll take a little bit longer to answer this question fully.

In the meantime, any reasons for start looping with index=1 instead of index=0 in "for(int index = 1; index < county.length && index < population.length; index++){"?

Also, what would be the example input and example output?
For example, user types in "Los Angeles" for the county, the result will be 12,000,000?

If you want the user to continue adding more counties and populations until the user wants to stop, then consider using a while loop instead of a for loop.